# How to run cordova phonegap through eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, cordova

I try to set and run the cordova phone gap using the instrustions from this `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVjCMXQGS_w`.

Until know I have
Java sdk
Android sdk
Node Js
Eclipse
And set the eclipse to have the ADT as proposed in video using `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

When I go to File --> New --> I can't find an android project but if I go to other there is an so I tried to insert an android project from existing code (because I have an example of phonegap to run but I can make it because I don't have the phonegap).

Taking a look to apache cordova site the have an npm command to install it but after that how can I open it and run to Eclipse?
Should I also run the npm for phonegap which is avaliable through phonegap site?
In video the instructions have a zip file but I can't find any zip file.

Thank you in advance for your guides. Any help will be very valiable for me.

Answer (score 0):

First you create the project with the cordova CLI

```
cordova create yourAppName com.your.package yourAppFolder
```

Then you add android platform

```
cordova platform add android
```

Now you can open the folder `yourAppFolder/platforms/android` from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Did u set your paths? JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, Cordova, etc? That kills me often.

You can generate a cordova/phonegap project. Look at jcesamobile post.